# ANTLR lexer patern [\p{Emoji}]+ is matching numbers

Tags: antlr, antlr4, lexer

The ANTLR4 lexer pattern [\p{Emoji}]+ is matching numbers. See screenshot. Note that it correctly rejects alpha chars. Is there an issue with the pattern?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\p{Emoji}` matches everything that has the Unicode Emoji property. Numbers do have that property, so `\p{Emoji}` is correct in matching them. Why though?

The Unicode standard defines any codepoint to have the Emoji property if it can appear as part of an Emoji. Numbers can appear as parts of emojis (for example I think shapes with numbers on them, which for them reason count as emojis, consist of a shape, followed by a join, followed by the number), so they have that property.

If you only want to match codepoints that are emojis by themselves, you can just use the `Emoji_Presentation` property instead. This will fail to match combined emojis though.

If you want to match any sequence that creates an emoji, I think you'll want to match something like "`Emoji_Presentation`, followed by zero or more of '(`Join_Control` or `Variation_Selector`) followed by `Emoji`'" (here you want `Emoji` instead of `Emoji_Presentation` because that's where numbers are allowed).

---

However, for the purpose of allowing emojis in identifiers (as opposed to a lexer rule to match emojis and nothing else), you don't actually have to worry about whether a number is part of an emoji or not, just that it doesn't appear as the first character of the identifier. So you could simply define your fragment for the starting character to only include `Emoji_Presentation` and then the fragment for continuing characters to include `Emoji` as well as `Join_Control` and `Variation_Selector`.

So something like this would work:

```
fragment IdStart
    : [_\p{Alpha}\p{General_Category=Other_Letter}\p{Emoji_Presentation}]
    ;

fragment IdContinue
    : IdStart
    // The `\p{Number}` might be redundant, I'm not sure. I don't know
    // whether there are any (non-ascii) numeric codepoints that don't
    // also have the `Emoji` property.
    | [\p{Number}\p{Emoji}\p{Join_Control}\p{Variation_Selector}]
    ;

Identifier: IdStart IdContinue*;
```

Of course that's assuming you actually want to allow characters besides emojis. The definition in your question only included emojis (or was meant to anyway), but since it was called `Identifier`, I'm assuming you just removed the other allowed categories to simplify it.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation. I didn't realize there are emojis that used numbers as a component of joined pairs, but that makes perfect sense.

Your explanation allowed me to correct my lexer rule. Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [the code](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/98dc2c0f0249a67b797b151da3adf4ffbc1fd6a1/tool/src/org/antlr/v4/unicode/UnicodeDataTemplateController.java) that seems to define emoji code points:

```java
UnicodeSet emojiRKUnicodeSet = new UnicodeSet("[\\p{GCB=Regional_Indicator}\\*#0-9\\u00a9\\u00ae\\u2122\\u3030\\u303d]");
```

it looks to be including digits (<s>why, I don't know</s>, checkout sepp2k's excellent explanation). <s>You can always [raise an issue](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues) if you think something is wrong.</s>

You could also just use a character class like this instead:

```
Identifier
 : [\u00a9\u00ae\u2000-\u3300\ud83c\ud000-\udfff\ud83d\ud000-\udfff\ud83e\ud000-\udfff]+
 ;
```

Comment: I didn't notice that bug in their set definition. Thank you for the pointer!

re: defining my own pattern - true, but I prefer to use the named property approach. The set is maintained by the author, updated with Unicode changes, etc.

Comment: @dleuck It's not a bug, it matches exactly what the Unicode standard says it should. The Unicode standard just defines the Emoji property somewhat confusingly.